# String of 0 and 1's question

Tags: contest-math

There are sixteen different ways of writing four-digit strings using 1s and 0s. Three
of these strings are 1010, 0100 and 1001. These three can be found as substrings
of 101001. There is a string of nineteen 1s and 0s which contains all sixteen strings
of length 4 exactly once. If this string starts with 1111, the last four digits are?
Interesting Question from the australian mathematics compeititon, not sure of an efficient approach.

Comment: See the diagram here ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#Construction ... you need to calculate the next one & then find a Hamiltonian path in that ... & note the last few characters.

Comment: If the string is reversed, it has the same property; if every $0$ is changed to a $0$ and every $0$ to a $1$, the string has the same property.  Therefore, if the answer to the question is unique, it must be $0000$.

Comment: I had a strong feeling that the answer is $000$, but couldn't come up with the reasoning that @saulspatz so concisely wrote. Could be an answer, but OP hasn't written any thoughts.

Comment: @saulspatz  I don't think this is correct, or at least it is not obvious...for two digit strings, for instance, the answer would be $11001$ and every digit is forced given the initial $11$.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure

Comment: For three digits the string $1110001011$ works, though I don't know if it is unique or not (given an initial $111$).

Comment: @lulu: but this does not have the same number of zeros and ones. Saulspatz answer is right as it specified that the string has 19 ones and 19 zeros.

Comment: @GCab I don't see that specification (as there are $19$ digits in the string, it is not possible).

Comment: @GCab   , Ah...I read the OP's claim as simply stating that there are $19$ entries in the string.  That's what you'd expect ($2^n+(n-1)$ for strings of length $n$).  If you go to length $38$ there is no way to avoid a great many repeats.

Comment: Ah, 19 is the length of the string ?!

Comment: @GCab.  Right.  It's $1111000010011010111$ (by [Debruijn methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#Construction)).  Indeed, the final $n$ digits will always be $01^{n-1}$ though I don't see a non-graphical way to see this.

Comment: @lulu: interesting, didn't know Debuijin method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the term after the initial string 1111. The only possibilities are 1111, 1110, or nothing. But since 1111 has been used, and this is the start of the sequence, the next term must be 1110.

Consider the term after 0111. The only possibilities are 1111, 1110, or nothing. But since 1111 and 1110 have been used, thus there is no next term. This means that, **if** a sequence exists, then the sequence must end with 0111.

---

Notes:

1. For completeness, we should show that at least one such string exists, which it does.
2. I don't consider the above a full complete solution. I'm guessing that the referenced AMC is MCQ, so this is sufficient to select the answer.
3. Of course, there is no preventing the possibility that another string `abcd` can have no term after it, hence note 1.

Comment: Is there hint that would think about the terms assoiscated with 0111?

Comment: @SelwynLiu Setting up of the graph correspondence is quite natural (even if you didn't know the theory behind it). From there, 1) Clearly, every node has an 2 out-edges and 2 in-edges (corresponding to adding 1/0 behind/infront). 2) We may guess that a Hamiltonian path/circuit exists (not immediately obvious for directed graphs). However, in general, there are many ways to complete a Hamiltonian path, so what could make this unique? 3) By symmetry of 0 and 1's, it's likely that if a Hamiltonian path exists, then a Hamiltonian circuit exists. (not always true)

Comment: 4) Notice that 1111 has an edge that maps back to itself. This makes that part of the Hamiltonian circuit unique, so we must have 0111 -> 1111 -> 1110. (Similarly, in the path, we must have 1000 -> 0000 -> 0001.) 5) This suggests that 0111 must be the unique answer. Let's check the out-edges make sense.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to a system of probability that I have developed for numerical systems and their vlaues based around the computational logic of a numerical triangle.

If you take the string 1111 below.

```
                                   0
                                  0 0
                                 0 0 0
                                1 1 1 1
```

You see I have turned it into a computational system based around a numerical triangle based on the value that divides the two values below it.

Now, everytime you generate a new sequence of this four value string where each quantity has a value of 0 or 1, the numerical sequence of the triangle above it changes.

You can discover the formulae for calculations based on the sequence above for what the string sequence is.

However I am yet to solve the problem of what the formuale for the calculations are, as such a concept of probability can be used to calculate the value and location of a string with infinite quanity and infinite value and therefore an infinite triangle.

I hope you like my idea.